# Disable the background of a uibutton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, isenabled

I have a circular custom menu with several buttons (with image and text). To not cut title, I had to unlarge button size, but the background of few buttons overlay partially the image or title of other button. That why I'd like to disable the background of buttons, or make image and/title only active.

How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: You can simply set the background color of the buttons to clear.

Comment: maybe set the background color to clear color?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you could change the background color quite easily with the following:

**Swift 3.0**

```
buttonName.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

**Swift 2.2 and prior**

```
buttonName.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Are your buttons overlapping because they're crowded? If so then from a design point of view I'd look at redesigning that aspect. Users may be misclicking if you have a number of overlapping crowded buttons.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot or some code to see?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I let backgroungColor to gray just to show you. I create buttons with a specific width in order the title is well writen. Maybe I can calculate the exact width of the title and attribute it to the button. That would solve partially the problem.